# meta-analysis of prognostic factor for models with different parameters

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, meta-analysis, multivariate-regression

I am trying to meta-analysis the OR of a variable (troponin) for a dichotomous outcome (mortality). There are several multivariate logistic regressions out there, but **none of them share the exact same set independent variables** (some of the models present Individual Patient Data, most of them just Aggregate Data).
Are you aware of any validated method  that would allow me to do this meta-analysis, what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that in theory you cannot meta-analyse coefficients when they have been adjusted for different sets of covariates. If you can identify a subset which use almost the same set then just use them and issue a strong warning in your write-up. Otherwise I think you are probably stuck.

Comment: for any interested, this paper seems to summarize current methodology https://diagnprognres.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s41512-019-0059-4